# Reformat JSON arrays/object in java

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

I am trying to reformat this json file to a different format. I never used jackson or gson before. I get the idea of it but I don't know how to implement it.

So what I have is a json file: file.json that contains:

```
 { 
     "Fruits": [
           {
             "name": "avocado",
             "organic": true
           },
           {
              "name": "mango",
              "organic": true
           }
    ]
}
```

What I want is to get in this format:

```
    { 
       "List Fruits":{
        "Fruits": [
           {
             "name": "avocado",
             "organic": true
           },
           {
              "name": "mango",
              "organic": true
           }
        ]
      }  
   }
```

Somehow add the "List Fruits" in the json file.

I am trying to use the jackson api but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

Assign the JSON to String variable, for example assign the above JSON to variable called `json`:

```
String json = "..." // here put your JSON text;
```

Prepare classes for your objects:

```
class Fruit {
    private String name;
    private boolean organic;
}

class Fruits {
    private List<Fruit> fruits;
}
```

then use Gson to convert JSON to your objects:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Fruits fruits = gson.fromJson(json, Fruits.class);
```

Next prepare wrapper class `ListOfFruits` for your `fruits` object:

```
class ListOfFruits {
    private Fruits listOfFruits;

    public ListOfFruits(Fruits fruits) {
        listOfFruits = fruits;
    }
}
```

Next pack your `fruits` object into another one:

```
ListOfFruits lof = new ListOfFruits(fruits);
```

And finally generate back the output JSON:

```
String newJson = gson.toJson(lof);
```

Comment: I created my Fruit and Fruits classes. I am not quite sure how to use the wrapper.

Comment: It is displayed in "Next pack your `fruits` object into another one" section above.

Comment: Got {"listofFruits":{}}. I am doing something wrong here.

Comment: I am stuck on how this ListOffruits access the Fruit and the Fruits class. If you can kindly help I would appreciate it.

Comment: @Woods I have created a sample for you. It's a maven project.
https://github.com/rajramo61/jsonwrapper

Comment: That's a problem. Is there a way not to use this as a maven project?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to create `POJO` model for reading and updating `JSON`. Using `Jackson`, you can read whole `JSON` payload to `JsonNode`, create a `Map` with required key and serialising to `JSON` back. See below example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

        JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(jsonFile);
        Map<String, JsonNode> output = Collections.singletonMap("List Fruits", root);

        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(output));
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
{
  "List Fruits" : {
    "Fruits" : [ {
      "name" : "avocado",
      "organic" : true
    }, {
      "name" : "mango",
      "organic" : true
    } ]
  }
}
```

Comment: It didn't like this. It gave me an error. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAutoDetect

Comment: @Woods, you need to add dependency to [jackson-annotations](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations). Do you use `Maven` or something similar?

Comment: Thanks. I have already solved this. I added jar files. It works. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to go over the entire array and find objects such as Fruits and Vegetables? I mean like the above and then when it finds Vegetables makes a list of Vegetables. I am trying this but no luck.

Comment: @Woods, this is a new problem comparing to what is asked in an original question. If my answer solves above problem, please, accept and upvote. And then ask another question and add a link to this one. It will be easier to find and answer it for other devs.
If you want to work with `JSON` payload it is a good idea to create a `POJO` model which represents your `JSON`. After that you should be able to iterate over objects and filter or change them if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend going through the documentations of Jackson or Gson libraries as you mentioned you are new.
I have created a sample git repo for this item. This sample uses Jackson API.

Visit https://github.com/rajramo61/jsonwrapper

```
final InputStream fileData = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("file.json");
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    InitialJson initialJson = mapper.readValue(fileData, InitialJson.class);
    System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(initialJson));
    final FinalJson finalJson = new FinalJson();
    finalJson.setListOfFruits(initialJson);
    System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(finalJson));
```

This is the Fruit class.

```
public class Fruit {
private String name;
private boolean organic;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public boolean getOrganic() {
    return organic;
}

public void setOrganic(boolean organic) {
    this.organic = organic;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Fruit{" +
            "name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", organic=" + organic +
            '}';
}
```

}

Here is FinalJson class detail. This is the class will wrap the initial json loaded from jsn file.

```
public class FinalJson {
private InitialJson listOfFruits;

@JsonProperty("List Fruits")
public InitialJson getListOfFruits() {
    return listOfFruits;
}

public void setListOfFruits(InitialJson listOfFruits) {
    this.listOfFruits = listOfFruits;
}
```

}

Here is InitialJson class detail. This is the class pulls data from json file.

```
public class InitialJson {
private List<Fruit> fruits;

@JsonProperty("Fruits")
public List<Fruit> getFruits() {
    return fruits;
}

public void setFruits(List<Fruit> fruits) {
    this.fruits = fruits;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "InitialJson{" +
            "fruits=" + fruits +
            '}';
}
```

}

You can fork the repo and close this in local and it should work fine.

Comment: It didn't like this. It gave me an error. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAutoDetect

Comment: @Woods Did you clone the repo https://github.com/rajramo61/jsonwrapper and tried? It's a working example.

Comment: Yeah. Works. Thank you so much! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Is there a way to use jars without a maven project?

Comment: Then you have to download the jars and use them in your class path. You can easily setup this is your IDE. I have created a sample project for this. If you are using IDE then you need to add lib directory in your classpath to refer to the jars.
https://github.com/rajramo61/json-wrapper-no-maven

Comment: Cool. This works. I am trying to identify from one additional object. I tried to create different classes for fruits and vegetables but now success. I mean is there a way to identify from the object Fruit or Vegetables and add as a list like the example above?

Comment: Woods, if this really helped then you can accept it as solution. For the other questions, you need to learn the jackson library and its uses.